# Downloading file displays unknown characters

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to make a download link on a page like this:

```
<a href="uploads/testfolder/excelfile.xlsx" target="_blank">Download here</a>`
```

When I click the link, it displays a page as shown in the picture below, which is also viewed in the same page.

[image]

It is supposed to download in the new window because I put `target="_blank"`. But the weird part is, when I try to right-click and open in a new window, it automatically prompts me to download the file.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I cannot see why the solution proposed by @I'm Liam should not work.

Comment: currently the only browser I'm using is google chrome

Comment: Works like a charm for me `Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a header response for the file to be downloaded properly.

Create a route:

```
Route::get('/download/{$filename}', [
    'as' => 'download-file',
    'uses' => 'YourController@download',
]);
```

In your controller:

```
public function download($filename)
{
    $path =  public_path('/yout/path/');
    $headers = [
              'Content-Type' => 'xlsx',
           ];

    return response()->download($path, $filename , $headers);
}
```

In your View:

```
<a href="{{route('download-file', filename.xlsx)}}" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Comment: how do i return this to controller?

Comment: From your controller you must be returning a view which has the download link right?

Comment: yes, but it does not hold any download link...just return the view page only

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Now i understand a bit, but how do I specify the file path?

Comment: Anyone know how to specify the path in this code?

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the HTML5 `download` attribute on the anchor to force a download in the browser when you click on the link.

```
<a href="uploads/testfolder/excelfile.xlsx" target="_blank" download>Download here</a>
```

Comment: nothing changed, still the same

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<a href="{{url('/')}}/uploads/testfolder/excelfile.xlsx" target="_blank" download>Download here</a>
```

or change the browser. This code downloads the file on my computer not open in new window.

Comment: its still the same...nothing is changed...this is weird

Comment: Have you changed the browser? and one more thing where you can see the screenshot that you mention in your question.

Comment: Yes I tried firefox, opera even the browser that my phone used, all produce the same result...the screenshot that i posted can be seen on the same page but different link when i click the download link

Comment: When I use my code then instead of opening the xlsx file directly it download first and by click on file it opened with the default application(Ms-excel or whatever). same thing happed with chrome, firefox and opera. Not showing the screenshot like yours.

Comment: Is this happend with other docs as well or could you please show the link that you were talking about(same page but different link...)